# Recovering passwords

Tags: google-chrome, data-recovery

My computer died. One day it worked fine, the next it didn't power up. They told me the motherboard has died.  I don't have any backups. They recovered all the data from C: drive, however, all my online passwords were stored in Chrome. Is there a way for me to recover them?

The computer that died had Win10 and now I'm using my old one with Win7. If there was a file, from which Chrome could recover the passwords, where could I find it?

Comment: Just transfer the Chrome user profile within AppData to your new computer.

Comment: Passwords are encrypted and unrecoverable in the user profile...

Comment: From the duplicate: "you will lose all stored passwords since they are encrypted using a Windows API that uses a machine/account specific key, which obviously will be different on any other machine/account."

Comment: @music2myear - You can store passwords in Chrome without encrypting them though.  At least you could when I was big enough fool to store passwords in a browser (not exactly the more secure).  Additionally, if a google account was used, it’s probably they were synced

Answer (score 0):

Try ChromePass from NirSoft:

https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/chromepass.html

[image]

> ChromePass is a small password recovery tool for Windows that allows
>   you to view the user names and passwords stored by Google Chrome Web
>   browser. For each password entry, the following information is
>   displayed: Origin URL, Action URL, User Name Field, Password Field,
>   User Name, Password, and Created Time. It allows you to get the
>   passwords from your current running system, or from a user profile
>   stored on external drive. You can select one or more items and then
>   save them into text/html/xml file or copy them to the clipboard.